# Lightning Node (MyNode) gone missing. How to recover funds?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, ln-closing-channels

I had a RaspPi/MyNode with a few LND channels open. The node has unfortunately gone missing/stolen and I'm trying to figure out the best way to get the funds back.

- I have access to my seed words for the LND wallet.
- I have access to a channel backup file.
- I don't have great internet currently, so doing a full node
  rebuild/restore will take days if not weeks to sync (unless someone
  has a better idea to shortcut this).

What would the best way to move the funds that were on those channels -- probably to an on-chain wallet? I'm guessing this would be a forced-close? Hopefully I can avoid any detrimental impact to those channel peers, not that the node was all that well connected/funded to do any significant routing, but still, trying to be as ethical as possible given the situation! :)

Comment: This question might be better suited to the lnd github, but perhaps someone here can help. Be wary, if you attempt to close channels based on an outdated channel state you may lose funds. Good luck!